# Rails app taking longer than 30 seconds for mongo query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, csv

I have a mongo db on remote, having a collection named *con_v*, here is the preview of one object.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
    "complete" : false,
    "far" : "something",
    "input" : {
        "number_of_apples" : 2,
        "type_of_apple" : "red"
    },
    "created_at" : ISODate("xxxxx"),
    "error" : false,
    "version_id" : ObjectId("someID"),
    "transcript" : "\nUser: \nScript: hello this is a placeholder script.\nScript: how many apples do you want?\n",
    "account_id" : null,
    "channel_id" : ObjectId("some channel ID"),
    "channel_mode_id" : ObjectId("some channel mode ID"),
    "units" : 45,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("xxxx")
}
```

I am using rails app to make queries from the remote mongo db, If I am fetching 20-50 records its responding but I need more than 1000 records at a time, I have a function creating csv file from that record, before it was working fine but now its taking longer than usual and freezing the server (total # of records are around 30K). Directly through mongo shell or using rails console the query is taking no time. Same thing if I am doing with cloned db at local machine app works fine..

*here is the code in model file which queries and generates csv file*

```
  def self.to_csv(con_v)
    version = con_v.first.version
    CSV.generate do |csv|
      fields = version.input_set_field_names
      extra_fields = ['Collected At', 'Far', 'Name', 'Version','Completed']

      csv << fields + extra_fields
      con_v.each do |con|
        values = con.input.values_at(*fields)
        extra_values = [
          con.created_at,
          con.units,
          con.far,
          version.name,
          con.complete
        ]
        csv << values + extra_values
      end
    end
```

**nutshell is app is taking longer on remote db, very slow mongo query but works fine wit local db, Debugged using pry, controller code is fine its getting the records as well just the respond time is slow on remote**

Comment: See here for some insights: https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby